# C# WPF - Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a `ContentDialogHost` that shows `ContentDialog`s in a `Grid`.

The `ShowDialog()` method handles showing the control in the host, and it returns a `ContentDialogResult`.

I want it to work like the Windows dialogs, you call `ShowDialog()`, the code stops until the user presses any of the dialog buttons.

Here's my implementation:

```
public ContentDialogResult ShowDialog(ContentDialog dialog)

        {
            // show host
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            _dialogResult = null;

            if (_currentDialog == null)
            {
                containerGrid.Children.Add(dialog);
                _currentDialog = dialog;
            }

            dialog.PrimaryButtonClick += (s, ev) => { _dialogResult = ContentDialogResult.Primary; };
            dialog.SecondaryButtonClick += (s, ev) => { _dialogResult = ContentDialogResult.Secondary; };

            while (_dialogResult == null)
            {
                if (this.Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted ||
                    this.Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                // THIS IS WHERE IT THROWS THE EXCEPTION BELOW
                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            CloseDialog();

            return _dialogResult.Value;
        }
```

This is wrapped in a Popups class, like so:

```
public ContentDialogHost.ContentDialogResult ShowDialog(ContentDialog dialog)
        {
            return mainwindow.contentdialogHost.ShowDialog(dialog);
        }
```

The exception ONLY occurs when calling `ShowDialog()` from an IsVisibleChanged event, such as here:

```
private void Page_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsVisible)
                ShowSubviewDebugDialog(); // this calls `ShowDialog()` from the above mentioned Popups class
        }
```

What can I do to fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: Offload the call to ShowSubviewDebugDialog onto the Dispatcher, using a dispatcher priority that is pretty low.

Comment: Can you give us the text of the exception?